# Is there an issue with Android's install process/algorithm?

Tags: android

I've been noticing for the last month or so that users of my Android app are receiving partial updates. What I mean by this is that their version is up to date and has most of the features that I had made live, but at the same time would still have code that I had changed weeks earlier. This did not affect users that did a clean install though, just the 99% that probably update an app like a normal user would. I could see how this could easily be caused by a lapse of concentration while using "git add" however I've exclusively used "git add -A" for probably the last two months so this is not the case. Recently I got fed up enough with it that I purposely changed some of the log statements here and there just so that if I ran into another user who's phone had partially updated, I could check it out and see what files were up to date or not. Amazingly, I found a mix and match of updated and outdated files. I contacted Google via chat and they said that they would transfer me to an email conversation with a technical representative, but I haven't heard back yet. Has anyone else encountered this issue and how would you go about solving this?

Comment: I've also noticed the same effect when emailing a copy of the APK file to someone to test it so it's probably not an issue strictly with the Play Store, but rather just with the general process of installing an APK file.